# MediaPlayer callbacks not firing after calling prepareAsync() from a Service

Tags: android, service, media-player

I'm working on writing a small app that will stream mp3 files. I'm using the NPR code, but having a strange problem with mediaPlayer.prepareAsync().

I'm using a trimmed down version of the [PlaybackService](https://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/trunk/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/PlaybackService.java) from the NPR app, which is getting started correctly. I am getting a reference to the service inside an OnClick handler inside an Activity, and calling listen() with the URL to the MP3 stream. The following (simplified) code is from my PlaybackService:

```
public void listen(String url) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException { 
    if (mediaPlayer == null) { 
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); 
    } 
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this); 
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this); 
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this); 
    mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this); 
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this); 
    synchronized (this) {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }
}

// ... lots of other code

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) { 
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Prepared"); 
    play();
}
```

I have the other callbacks defined as well. I can see from LogCat that the MediaPlayer is loading the stream and buffering, as I see the following messages:

```
AwesomePlayer  I  calling prefetcher->prepare()
AwesomePlayer  I  prefetcher is done preparing
```

But my onPrepared method never gets called. If I add a timer and try to call play() on the MediaPlayer at some point after I see the above log messages, the media players plays, so it is indeed entering into the Prepared state.

If I replace the call to prepareAsync() with prepare(), the player just works. This is all on 2.2, which I have been reading seems to have some issues, but the problem I'm having doesn't seem related, as the stream works fine when prepare() is used.

I did notice that the Content-Length on the the stream is quite large (450MB), but since I can call play on the Media Player without getting an exception, it appears to be handling this OK.

The only other change is that in the NPR app, the service is being bound to and the playback started from inside a View object (while in my app, this happens inside an Activity).

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Nearly every time i see these errors it seems to be unexplainable low level behavior of the MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have created the mediaplayer in a thread that has a [looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html), which is required for the callbacks to work properly.